# Adding Gravity to Animations

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I'm trying to understand how to add some physics like gravity and wind into my animations.  I can't quite wrap my head around how to make this ball bounce as if it has gravity... each update I am accumulating the forces, applying it to the velocity, then clearing the forces.  But the only way I can think to make it bounce back up is to change the Y direction..but then it just keeps going until it hits the top.  Is there something obvious I'm missing? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks for reading

```js
var C, canvas, context = null;
var gravity = {x:0, y:1};
var wind = {x:0.4, y:0};
var height = 140;
var width = 300;

function Ball(x,y,w,h) {
  var ball = this;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.xVelocity = 0;
  this.yVelocity = 0;
  this.xDirection = 1;
  this.yDirection = 1;
  
  this.update = function() {
   ball.applyForce(gravity);
    //ball.applyForce(wind);
   
    ball.x += (ball.xVelocity * ball.xDirection);
    ball.y += (ball.yVelocity * ball.yDirection);
    
    if((ball.x + ball.w) >= width) {
     //ball.xDirection = -1;
        ball.x = width - ball.w / 2 ;
        ball.xVelocity = -ball.xVelocity
    } else if(ball.x <= 0) {
     //ball.xDirection = 1;
        ball.xVelocity = ball.xVelocity
    }
    
    if((ball.y + ball.h) >= height) {
     //ball.yDirection = -1;
        ball.y = height - ball.w;
        ball.yVelocity = -ball.yVelocity
    } else if(ball.y <= 0) {
       //ball.yDirection = 1;
        ball.yVelocity = ball.yVelocity
    }
    
    //ball.clearForces();
  }
  
  this.draw = function() {
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.w,0,2*Math.PI);
   context.stroke();
  }
  
  this.applyForce = function(force) {
  ball.xVelocity += force.x;
   ball.yVelocity += force.y;
  }
  
  this.clearForces = function(force) {
  ball.xVelocity = 0;
   ball.yVelocity = 0;
  }
}

function Canvas( ) {
var CV = this;
var balls = new Array();
balls.push(new Ball(100, 10, 10, 10));

  this.loop = function() {
  CV.update();
  CV.draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(CV.loop);
  }
  
  this.update = function() {
   for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
     balls[i].update();
    }
  }
  
  this.draw = function() {
   context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
   for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
     balls[i].draw();
    }
  }
}


canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
C = new Canvas( );
C.loop();
```

```css
#canvas {border:1px solid #d4d4d4; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="140"></canvas>
```

Comment: Instead of changing direction when you hit the floor, negate the velocity: `ball.yVelocity = -ball.yVelocity`

Comment: @Matt L. thank you, but I am not having luck with this. Is it the order that I am doing it? I edited the snippet and tried. I should've pointed out that I actually did try to reverse the velocity.  The best result I got was the ball being stuck on the ground but it never bounced back up.  Please see the snippet now, the ball just keeps going.

Comment: Sorry, this is not going to help directly, but it seemed so relevant. http://www.uselesspickles.com/jsballs/ (and it works with IE6, written like 10 years ago)

Comment: Try resetting the ball's position to the floor as well as negate the velocity. On the frame after you flip the velocity, you're still below the threshold

Comment: @Matt L. thanks Matt, I added this to the snippet but it sticks to the bottom instead of bouncing back upward.  Seems like a step in the right direction though.

Comment: @RON2015 you clear your forces at the end of each frame, which means on the next frame, gravity is all that makes up your velocity, which pulls it down below the threshold again. Try not clearing the forces

Comment: @Matt L. removing clearForces seemed to work...but that actually makes me a bit more confused... I thought it was important to clear the forces or they spiral out of control because they keep accumulating each update.

Comment: @RON2015 in game physics, you typically have three values: Position, Velocity, and Acceleration. Position is where you are, Velocity is where the object is moving, and Acceleration is what changes your velocity. In your example, adding gravity would be your acceleration. And since it is constant, it won't amount to a large force. Now, if you were adding multiple forces, then you may want to use an acceleration variable and yes, that would need to be reset every frame

Comment: @Matt L. I don't understand why the bounce gets smaller and finally stops? There is no "drag" variable so shouldn't the ball just keep bouncing back to it's starting location?

Answer (score 0):

In kinematics, simple motion can sometimes be expressed as `v(t) = aΔt` where `v` is velocity at `t` seconds and `aΔt` is the acceleration times the interval `Δt`.

A way to simulate this could be to either calculate the `ball.yVelocity` component as `(-someAcceleration) * someTimeIndex` or to preform a function like
 `var ball.yVelocity = ball.yVelocity - someFactor` each loop.

**EDIT 1:** I would also set up a separate variable like`yVelocityAbs` in order to handle the magnitude of `ball.yVelocity` so as not to screw up your direction each time the ball bounces. Good luck!

**EDIT 2:** Try updating your clearForces() function like this:

```
this.clearForces = function(force) {
         ball.xVelocity = 0;
        //ball.yVelocity = 0;
  }
```

It should work! Albeit a fairly janky representation, the simulation should fit better. I would suggest adding some functionality that resets the ball, though.

Comment: Sounds correct, any way you can fix his snippet using the "Copy snippet to my answer" button?

Comment: @JuanMendes sure! I will post an updated snippet in a bit, once I figure out how to attach it.

Comment: @Nick S thank you Nick, but if I'm being honest what you said is going over my head a bit... I'm not sure how I can implement that in the code.